# Counting the amount of occurrences in a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, counting

I am fairly new to python, but I haven't been able to find a solution to my problem anywhere.

I want to count the occurrences of a string inside a list of tuples.

Here is the list of tuples:

```
list1 = [
         ('12392', 'some string', 'some other string'),
         ('12392', 'some new string', 'some other string'),
         ('7862', None, 'some other string')
        ]
```

I've tried this but it just prints 0

```
for entry in list1:
    print list1.count(entry[0])
```

As the same ID occurs twice in the list, this should return:

```
2
1
```

I also tried to increment a counter for each occurrence of the same ID but couldn't quite grasp how to write it.

*EDIT:
Using Eumiro's awesome answer. I just realized that I didn't explain the whole problem.
I actually need the total amount of entries which has a value more than 1. But if I try doing:

```
for name, value in list1:

    if value > 1:
        print value
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Too many values to unpack
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Maybe [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) could solve your problem:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(elem[0] for elem in list1)
```

returns

```
Counter({'12392': 2, '7862': 1})
```

It is fast since it iterates over your list just once. You iterate over entries and then try to get a count of these entries within your list. That cannot be done with `.count`, but might be done as follows:

```
for entry in list1:
    print(sum(1 for elem in list1 if elem[0] == entry[0]))
```

But seriously, have a look at `collections.Counter`.

**EDIT**: *I actually need the total amount of entries which has a value more than 1.*

You can still use the `Counter`:

```
c = Counter(elem[0] for elem in list1)
sum(v for k, v in c.iteritems() if v > 1)
```

returns `2`, i.e. the sum of counts that are higher than 1.

Comment: `Counter` makes it so simple

Comment: Thanks! That is really simple! I just realized that I didn't explain the whole problem. I updated the original question.

Comment: @eumiro - Awesome! Thanks alot! The stuff you're doing in sum is called comprehension, right?

Comment: @Mackwerk - a **generator comprehension** to be exact.

Comment: In Python 3, `c.iteritems()` needs to be replaced by `c.items()`.

Answer (score 7):

`list1.count(entry[0])` will not work because it looks at each of the three tuples in `list1`, eg. `('12392', 'some string', 'some other string')` and checks if they are equal to `'12392'` for example, which is obviously not the case.

@eurmiro's answer shows you how to do it with `Counter` (which is the best way!) but here is a poor man's version to illustrate how `Counter` works using a dictionary and the `dict.get(k, [,d])` method which will attempt to get a key (`k`), but if it doesn't exist it returns the default value instead (`d`):

```
>>> list1 = [
         ('12392', 'some string', 'some other string'),
         ('12392', 'some new string', 'some other string'),
         ('7862', None, 'some other string')
]
>>> d = {}
>>> for x, y, z in list1:
        d[x] = d.get(x, 0) + 1


>>> d
{'12392': 2, '7862': 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed some extra functionality that Counter didn't have. I have a list of tuples that the first element is the key and the second element is the amount to add. @jamylak solution was a great adaptation for this!

```
>>> list = [(0,5), (3,2), (2,1), (0,2), (3,4)]

>>> d = {}
>>> for x, y in list1:
    d[x] = d.get(x, 0) + y

>>> d
{0: 7, 2: 1, 3: 6}
```