# list of tuples to Counter or a dictionary of counts

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of tuples. For each key I'd like to count the number of distinct values.

For example,

Given the following list:

`[(k1, 400), (k1, 500), (k2, 600), (k2, 600), (k3, 600)]`

I'd like to produce the following:

`{k1: 2, k2: 1, k3: 1}`

explanation:

`k1` has two values (400, 500). `k2` has only one value (600)

What's the Pythonic way to do that?

Comment: What you have tried and where do you get stuck? Even not very Pythonic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting the amount of occurrences in a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16013485/counting-the-amount-of-occurrences-in-a-list-of-tuples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from collections import defaultdict

list_of_tuples = [
    ("k1", 400),
    ("k1", 500),
    ("k2", 600),
    ("k2", 600),
    ("k3", 600),
]

dict_of_sets = defaultdict(set)

for key, value in list_of_tuples:
    dict_of_sets[key].add(value)

result = {key: len(value) for key, value in dict_of_sets.items()}
```

Comment: Not sure this is considered more `Pythonic`.  Find out the link provided by @Luuk by `Counter` is more Pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Dict Comprehensions, will look something like this:

```
x = [(k1, 400), (k1, 500), (k2, 600), (k2, 600), (k3, 600)]
dictionary = {k: v for k,v in x}
print(dictionary)
```

Output:

```
{'k1': 500, 'k2': 600, 'k3': 600}
```